# UIImageView, tap and recognition

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have an UIImageViews with `userInteractionEnabled`, and i want to know with image i currently tap. What i should do to know that? I have a poster wall and class for that `ThumbPosterModel` there i have all poster information with i want to pass through.

So my code is:

```
for (ThumbPosterModel *tPoster in _thumbsPosterStack) {

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:tPoster.thumb];
    imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(i, imageView.frame.origin.y, imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height);

    [_posterWallScrollView addSubview:imageView];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap =
    [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageTapped:)];
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
}
```

And then i have:

```
-(IBAction)imageTapped:(id)sender {
    //something do here, but know i don't know what.
}
```

Should i subclass `UIImageView` that should contains all ThumbPosterModel params? I don't think it is good idea, but i can't figure any other solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok this is very simple just add `tag` proprty of each image with appropriate and distinct value other then `0` and use that proprty to identify the image :)

Happy Coding :)

Comment: yes using tags is the easiest solution in your case. Give every imageView a different tag (which is an integer) -(IBAction)imageTapped:(id)sender has the sender (which is the UIImageView), you can cast it to a UIImageView and get the tag.

Comment: But what if I don't know how many image i will have? And how to "translate" this tag after tap to image again? where to store it? Please, give example code.

Comment: Nevermind, i understand completly now! Thanks for than, it's very simple that way ;)

Answer (score 1):

When the gesture recognizer is fired the sender in the action is the recognizer, so you can get the UIView it is attached to by calling `[sender view];`

So you could write a method which searched the thumbs poster stack and found the poster with the matching thumb, but it would probably be easier to create a `UIImageView` subclass which contains a reference to the poster. So when you get the view just do

```
PosterImageView *selectedPosterView = (PosterImageView *) [sender view];
ThumbPosterModel *selectedModel = selectedPosterView.model;
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a tag to your each imageView.

Each for loop iteration add your image view to a `NSMutableArray` (arrayRef).

Accessing the tag of image view when you tap the image view(tagImage) .

then

```
UIIMageView *imageViewR=[arrayRef objectAtIndex:tagImage-1];
```

The `imageViewR` is the tap imageView